# how can we use a variable as "string[] fullNames" on readMetadata?

Tags: apex, trigger, api, soap-api, metadata-api

Below given is the syntax for readMetadata call for fetching WorkflowRule specific to an object .

```
ReadResult = metadataConnection.readMetadata(string WorkflowRule, string[] fullNames);
```

I want to know that Is there any way to use a variable(which has the object name) in place of "string[] fullNames" ?

Below is the code snippet,
while I am trying to execute it , it gives NULL for mdInfoWorkflow.fullname
Note: Cobj is a FileProperties type list of all object

```
 ....
    for (MetadataService.FileProperties n : Cobj) 
                {
 readResultWorkflow = service.readMetadata('WorkflowRule', new String[] {n.fullname});
                          mdInfoWorkflow = readResultWorkflow.getRecords();
                          system.debug('mdInfoWorkflow :' +mdInfoWorkflow);
...
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Metadata for workflow is named 'Workflow'. Try it .

Answer (score 1):

You can use any list of strings you want. These two syntaxes are identical:

```
List<String> aNames = new List<String>();
String[] bNames = new String[]();
aNames.add('Workflow_A');
bNames.add('Workflow_B');
```

You can also instantiate them with elements inline:

```
List<String> aNames = new List<String> { 'Workflow_A' };
String[] bNames = new String[] { 'Workflow_B' };
```